# Run-time operators in C++

Tags: c++

What is the definition of compile-time and run-time operator in C++?

I know that `sizeof()` is a compile-time operator in C++ but which are the run-time operators?

---

<sub>([Originally posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30164886/560648) for [c](/questions/tagged/c)[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) by [bc90](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4818243/bc90); I did not wish to waste the answer that I posted before it became clear he only wanted a C answer. Hey, perhaps this can help "clarify" someone's "doubts" one day.)</sub>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not as simple as that. There is no "list of runtime operators" or "list of compile-time operators". There are *operators*, and many of them may be optimised to be "executed" by the compiler rather than coded into the program as an operation to be performed at runtime.

The obvious one is `sizeof`, which *never* needs to be deferred until program execution. In fact, speaking generally, operators which act on *types* may be expected to be purely a semantic operation with no reliance on run-time information. As another example, there is absolutely no reason for `const_cast` to have any run-time relevance, seeing as `const` doesn't even exist in your compiled program. A `static_cast` *may* be optimised away, but that would depend on what the relevant conversion operators do.

What may not be so obvious is that many expressions that invoke, say, arithmetic operators, may be optimised away.

For example:

```
const int x = 2 + 4;
```

That addition is not going to be performed at runtime unless your compiler is very, very silly. But does that make `operator+` a "compile-time operator"? No.

And the function call operator `()` is only ever going to be invokable at compile-time if the applicable `constexpr` rules apply, or the function definition is visible in the same translation unit as the call site and is sufficiently trivial.

Whilst we're at it, `reinterpret_cast` disqualifies an expression from being `constexpr`. This is reasonably unintuitive but, according to the rationale in [CWG issue #1384](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1384):

> Although `reinterpret_cast` was permitted in address constant expressions in C++03, this restriction has been implemented in some compilers and has not proved to break significant amounts of code. CWG deemed that the complications of dealing with pointers whose tpes *[sic]* changed (pointer arithmetic and dereference could not be permitted on such pointers) outweighed the possible utility of relaxing the current restriction.

My point is that, really, it's not worth trying to come up with general rules for this: the process of C++ program compilation is just *not* that straightforward. You have to examine what your program is doing on a case-by-case basis.

However, I do appreciate that you are trying to answer a poor exam question. For that, you have my sympathies.

Comment: the weird thing is that `reinterpret_cast` disqualifies an expression from  being `constexpr`

Comment: Yah, really: N4296 [expr.const]/2.13

Comment: @TemplateRex: It's not that I didn't believe you. Any idea why?

Comment: @TemplateRex both gcc and clang allow an exception [using __builtin_constant_p](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24400015/1708801) ... the *is magical* comment made me chuckle.